# SQL statement workflow

Tags: mysql, sql

Every month we need to create a statement based off of a CSV file. Here is an example:

```
SELECT Name, OrderID, Product, Price
From Orders
Where OrderID = (here is where I am stuck);
```

So basically every month we get a new set of roughly 50 to 60 OrderID values in CSV format. How can I create a statement that outputs Name, OrderID, Product, Price for these OrderID's?

Comment: are you planning on hard-coding the order ids into the query? Or do you want to use a parameter with the list in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT Name, OrderID, Product, Price
From Orders
Where OrderID In ('row1', 'row2', 'row3', ...);
```

Comment: It should be enough to build the string list from the CSV data, how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can put the IDs in a comma delimited list you would use an IN clause:

```
SELECT Name, OrderID, Product, Price 
From Orders 
Where OrderID IN (23,567,78);
```